# Site Columns & Content Types Missing during VS Development

Tags: sharepoint, content-type, site-column

Just getting into SharePoint development however we're encountering an issue following nearly every tutorial!

Site Columns & Content Types do not seem to appear in SharePoint after Deploying an app via VS 2013!

We're currently following [this](http://channel9.msdn.com/series/Developing-SharePoint-2013-Core-Solutions/02) Channel9 tutorial. Fairly straightforward - they create an app, add a Column & Content Type and at 37 minutes in they deploy their app to SharePoint. After doing so they navigate to Site Settings -> Site Columns and can see the column created in the project. 
We however don't see this! The 'site column' and 'content type' aren't listed in SharePoint 2013.

This occurs with every tutorial we've followed, the content type and column simply isn't there. Any ideas where we're going wrong? Are we missing a step?

**Note**: The only differences from what we're doing to the Channel9 tutorial is:

- We create an "App for SharePoint 2013" whereas they're using a "SharePoint 2013 Empty Project" template.
- They seem to be using a local sandbox environment and we're using a Developer Site on our Office 365 / SharePoint online instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That the difference:

> We create an "App for SharePoint 2013" whereas they're using a
>   "SharePoint 2013 Empty Project" template.

When develop app your create *"another site"* isolated from your host where your app is installed, your site column and content type are here.

Try to create a Sharepoint 2013 Empty Project and you see the Site Column and Content Type on your host site.

Check this link to see [Apps for SharePoint compared with SharePoint solutions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163114.aspx)

Comment: I'm not allowed to create an empty project I get an error stating "The required version of SharePoint Foundation 2013 or SharePoint Server 2013 is not installed on this system."  I'm referred to this URL: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869.aspx

Comment: I don't have 16GB of RAM and don't want to install the entire SharePoint on my local development machine either. Is there a workaround or tutorials targeted at deploying to the Online SharePoint do you know?

Comment: also, are you basically stating that as a developer, it doesn't matter that I cannot see the site-columns and content-types in this type of development?

Comment: Obviously Sharepoint Solutions require Visual Studio on the same machine where Sharepoint is installed. Provide SiteColumns or Content Type via App (To host site) is also possible but you must do via code (Javascript) see REST a CSOM (JSOM) or Provided Host.